# how can i submit my values in jsp page to a hibernate program

Tags: hibernate, jsp

i created a jsp page which consist of registration form by clicking submit button the values must be stored in the data base can any one suggest the process of doing that application only by using jsp and hibernate

Comment: This is basic stuff ! Show us what have you tried .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using only JSP and hibernate is not recommened. JSP is meant for view part only and it should not perform any operation. You can use MVc pattern.

- A jsp which submits the form
- A servlet which is called from the jsp which submits form
- Use business methods for performing operations on data.
- Call those operations in servlet to persist the data accordingly